# Creating SVG fragments with Javascript and Strings

Tags: javascript, svg, fragment

I've seen several examples about how to use the DOM api to create SVG fragments from within Javascript, but I'm curious is there something I can use to create a SVG fragment from a string similar to innerHTML.  I've tried this following:

```
var svg = '<foreignObject><body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><p>Hello World</p></foreignObject>'
var range = document.createRange();
return range.createContextualFragment(svg);
```

Problem is createContextualFragment() with SVG blows up with an exception in Chrome.  So is there a cross browser way to do this?

Comment: have you ever used raphael.js ?  It's awesome for producing SVG

Comment: I'm more interested about the DOM API as provided by the browsers rather than using another javascript library.  One for my own curiosity and two I figure I should be able to do this without needing a new library at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here is what I did:

```
parseXML('<foreignObject xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><p id="seriesTitle"></p><p id="seriesValue"></p><p style="margin:0;text-align:center;" id="seriesDate"></p></body></foreignObject>')
```

Since parseXml() isn't exactly cross browser supported I have this code at the top:

```
if (typeof parseXML=='undefined') {
    window.parseXML = function (s,doc) {
        doc = doc || document;
        var doc2=(new DOMParser()).parseFromString(s, "text/xml");
        return doc.adoptNode(doc2.documentElement);
    }
}
```

Then I can use jQuery to query instead the fragment and set the values I'd like:

```
jQuery('#seriesTitle', detailChart.mytooltip).text( point.series.name );
jQuery('#seriesValue', detailChart.mytooltip).text( point.y );
jQuery('#seriesDate', detailChart.mytooltip).text( date.getMonth() + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear() );
```

Problem is VML doesn't support anything like foreignObject.  SVG is so close to being a great solution for building applications that doesn't have all the HTML headaches.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something like `innerHTML`, your original code should have the range select the  element, to set up the right parser context. Then Chrome should fix http://crbug.com/107982

Assuming the bug was fixed, here's how I would parse a SVG fragment.
https://github.com/pwnall/ddr/blob/master/javascripts/base/pwnvg.coffee#L184

In the meantime, I came up with a solution that is very similar to yours, but tells `DOMParser` that it's dealing with SVG contents. I think your solution is better for your specific case, but my code is a bit closer to `innerHTML` (actually I aim to match `insertAdjacentHTML`).

https://github.com/pwnall/ddr/blob/master/javascripts/base/pwnvg.coffee#L169